# dplyr::mutate a timestamp

Tags: r, datetime, posixct, dplyr

I have access to read data from database with messed up timezone at their dates. For several reasons it can't be fixed at database side and I don't have even rights to do it.

I created workaround in R that works well in meaning that my code transforms time to correct time. Only issue is that it might be bit slow if i load lot of data - like 1 milion rows or more and code is nothing fancy.

Data basically looks like this, there is noting special about it. Just usual data stored in db and date.

```
df <- read.table(text="
 id    date
 1     2013-01-25 10:11:21
 2     2013-02-21 13:10:00
", header=TRUE)
```

My code is

```
fix_timezone <-
 mutate(
  fixed = as.POSIXct(as.character(date), tz = "UTC"),
  date = as.POSIXct(format(as.POSIXct(fixed ), tz="Europe/Berlin"))
)
```

If I use just UTC timezone, it loads some of data with +1 hour. But not all of them because of daylight time changes. Do you guys know how to improve speed of my code and maybe how to make it prettier?

Comment: Maybe just use `df$date <- as.POSIXct(format(as.POSIXct(as.POSIXct(as.character(date), tz = "UTC")), tz="Europe/Berlin"))` instead of your `mutate` structure. I don't know if it's faster, but it is, IMHO, simpler.

Comment: And about `fancyness`: I don't think code needs to be fancy. Code needs to be as easy as possible. Which is different from fancy IMHO.